# Current Tcl/Tk starpack and proper use case?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I had the intention of attempting to build (move) a desktop application in Tcl/Tk after reading about it first on the SQLite web site.  I read over some older books on the openlibrary.org and purchased a new printing of one of them.  It appears to be a decent text but every reference to a web site for some utility to build a starpack appears to be outdated.

I can't find a tclkit. One site that states you can build one online fails.  I came across Freewrap which is as recent as Sep. 2020 but is still behind the most recent version of Tcl/Tk. I don't understand what ActiveTcl is from its site.

Is this something that one can compile from sources or is it available only from one of these utilities?

I'm not trying to criticize it but would like to make sure I'll be able to build an executable at the end of the project and that I start within the correct set up.

Perhaps I've misunderstood something.  I've been using C compiled with the SQLite amalgamation and the native-messaging API of a web extension to use a browser as the UI. It works pretty well; however, after reading about Tcl/Tk, it appears that all the same can be done more efficiently and without the browser and still connect to a server when needed through Tcl.  I prefer that a lot.

Ultimately, I want to build something similar to a highly searchable library with pre-built tables, similar to the structure of a Biblical concordance, such that searches across texts can be performed quickly and compared, and linked to other resources.  When I have new resources available, I'd like to be able to easily add the necessary components for the user from a server such that those resources become part of the searchable content.

I realize that is sort of vague but is this a good use case for Tcl/Tk, can it be made into a starpack, and, if so, where can the current utility or method of making one be found?

Thank you.

---

Came across this [article](https://www.magicsplat.com/blog/starpack-example/) which was helpful. There is also a book as recent as 2017.

Comment: I'm not familiar with starpack but if I'm not mistaken Freewrap has an option to let you choose your own tcl executable to wrap with

Comment: Freewrap source code is also available from Sourceforge. It's not as convenient as having access to a git repo but it's all there in a single zip file if you want to compile it yourself: https://sourceforge.net/projects/freewrap/

Comment: A few years ago I was looking into how to make an exe too and I think I found out how to do that on a google group discussion. Right now, I can use the file `sdx.kit` (old version still works fine) and a tclkit file (I just tested [Kitgen](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kbskit/) from [this article](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tclkit+Kitgen+Build+System) and could get a kit from the latest Tcl). Otherwise, I can't really say whether this is a good case for Tcl/Tk or not.

Comment: @slebetman @Jerry Thanks for the responses. Since I'm using Windows I used `magicsplat` that is mentioned in the article and the author's book provides some information also concerning `sdx.kit` and `tclkit` from `rkeene.org`. Thanks for pointing out Freewrap and Kitgen links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A starkit is an archive format (based on the Metakit single-file database format) that has been used to distribute Tcl applications and extensions; these can be either platform-specific or cross-platform, depending on what you put inside. Tclkit (or its more modern versions from [Kitgen](https://sourceforge.net/projects/kbskit/)) is a single-file Tcl distribution that can read and execute a starkit; it's naturally platform-specific. A starpack is a combination of tclkit base runtime and starkit-packaged application.

As the whole starkit/tclkit system is based on Tcl's virtualised filesystem support, you can put pretty much anything you want inside a *kit, *including extension DLLs.* About the only thing that it's not a great idea to put in is a database (such as an SQLite DB file); while you can put a copy inside, you'll need to extract it for use. I mention this because it sounds like including a database would be highly appropriate for your application.

For update, the simplest method is to just have users download a new copy of the application. Since you can make that into one pre-packaged file, this is very easy for them to handle updates for. (You can do automatic updating, but then you have to keep track of the file holding the updates; not all platforms allow updating a running executable.)

---

Tcl 8.7 will include a packaging technology for doing similar things, though based on a different file format. That's all still alpha though.